# passing input value to asp-route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-input, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Ok so I am trying to pass the value from the input Quantite in the asp-route-qt, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. This one `asp-route-idBillet` is working just fine but the other isn't. If anyone could help me solve this problem with an example it would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Edit: I should of specified that the model I am using for the view can't have Quantite as an attribute. The model contains four types of tickets. Each ticket contains a title, a description, a price and an Id. Basically what this means is that I can't use an `asp-for` tag for the input Quantite.

Here's my view:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="row">
    @foreach(var billet in Model)
    {
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" asp-for="Titre">@billet.Titre</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" asp-for="Descript">@billet.Descript</p>
                    <label for="Quantite">Quantité:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="Quantite" id="Quantite">

                    <a class="btn btn-secondary" asp-controller="Billet" asp-action="AjouterBillet" asp-route-idBillet="@billet.Id" asp-route-qt>Ajouter au panier</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    }
    </div>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Aller au panier" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Here's my controller action

```
    private readonly ZooDbContext _zooDbContext;
    private readonly Panier _panier;

    public BilletController(ZooDbContext zooDbContext, Panier panier)
    {
        _zooDbContext = zooDbContext;
        _panier = panier;
    }

    public IActionResult AjouterBillet(int idBillet, int qt)
    {
        Billet billet = _zooDbContext.Billet.Find(idBillet);
        _panier.Ajouter(billet, qt);
        return RedirectToAction("Liste");
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I found that works.

Here's the view:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="row">
    @foreach(var billet in Model)
    {
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" asp-for="Titre">@billet.Titre</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" asp-for="Descript">@billet.Descript</p>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("AjouterBillet", "Billet"))
                    {
                        <label for="Quantite">Quantité:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="Quantite" id="Quantite">

                        <input value="Ajouter au panier" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" asp-controller="Billet" asp-action="AjouterBillet"
                               asp-route-idBillet="@billet.Id">
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    }
    </div>
    <br>

    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Panier" asp-action="AfficherPanier">Aller au panier</a>
</form>
```

Here's is the action:

```
public class BilletController : Controller
{
    private readonly ZooDbContext _zooDbContext;
    private readonly Panier _panier;

    public BilletController(ZooDbContext zooDbContext, Panier panier)
    {
        _zooDbContext = zooDbContext;
        _panier = panier;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AjouterBillet(int idBillet, int Quantite)
    {
        Billet billet = _zooDbContext.Billet.Find(idBillet);
        _panier.Ajouter(billet, Quantite);
        return RedirectToAction("Liste");
    }
}
```